# ifconfig and interfaces

Tags: macos, interface, ip, ifconfig

just a question for my understanding. on my mac when I use `ifconfig` command on my mac I get the following interfaces:

- en0
- en1
- lo0
- fw0
- vment0
- vment1

I don't understand why there are so many. I understand that eth0 would be for LAN connections, and that en0 is the wireless connection. But macbook only has one airport..so why en1 as well? not sure what vments are for either.

Comment: I would imagine that you have a VWare installtion of some sort to get the vment* entries, (which are often the NAT or bridged interfaces of the VM server).  There has been a similar question before http://superuser.com/questions/267660/mac-os-x-please-explain-ifconfig-output

Comment: apologies! you are right. i only searched SO

Comment: Just closing as off-topic instead of migrating to avoid creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's no `eth0` on default configuration of OS X. By default, `en0` and `en1` are your physical network connections (wired and wireless LAN). `lo0` is the loopback interface. `fw0` is the IP over Firewire interface; and `vmnet` interfaces are installed by VMware for network communication with virtual machines.

Comment: so i could have 5 IP addresses? (if you count 127.0.0.1) I could appear as 5 computers to the network?

Comment: @lollercoaster Yes. Those networks are not necessarily related, however. Moreover, you can create virtual interfaces on top of a physical interface and have multiple IP addresses on a single underlying adapter.

Comment: @Merhrdad I see. Like virtual apache servers? And what do you mean by  "Those networks are not necessarily related"?

Comment: @lol 1) I'm not sure what exactly you mean by a virtual Apache server, but Apache can be multiplexed in two ways; first, hosting multiple domains on a single IP endpoint (IP and port combination,) which is implemented at HTTP level, not TCP (i.e. a single socket will listen for connections for all domains.); second, having Apache listen on different IP endpoints (either ports, or actual addresses). For the latter, one can leverage from having multiple addresses on a single network interface. -- 2) I mean, you'll have 5 addresses, but each of them is only valid on its respective network...

Comment: ...(cont'd) implementation of multiple IPs over a single physical network interface is easy. IP is completely irrelevant in the Ethernet protocol. The kernel has to do a couple things: receive and process packets directed at multiple IP addresses and respond to ARP packets sent to those IP addresses with the same MAC address.

Answer (score 21):

`en0` and `en1` are your physical wired/wireless cards.

`lo0` is the loopback device, which is used for entirely internal communication, ie. between two applications both running on your PC.

`fw0` is for networking over firewire I believe.

`vment*` - is used by VMWare Fusion to provide networking to your virtual machines, and there's likely to be one per VM you have set up.

Comment: oh ok. so why do I not get a local IP address (192.168.x.x) when I run `ifconfig`? I only see my actual IP 1x.196.x.x

Comment: @lollercoaster Which interface are you looking at? Also, there are several different local IP ranges (10.x, 192.168.x and one other one too), you may simply be on a different private range.